# Am I still Catholic?

Tags: catholicism

I would like to find out, I was confirmed in my Catholic Church, and used to go often. However as I got older, I could never get to church, as my parents did not wish to take me. I then went overseas for a year, came home and moved to another town. I have not been back to a Catholic Church until this past Sunday.

I want to know, since I have been gone for so long, what can I do to enter the Church properly? I love being Catholic and when asked I let people know that I am Catholic. I want to enter the Church correctly. If someone can please give me guidance.

Comment: This is something that you should discuss with a priest, since we cannot give pastoral advice. I'm not a Catholic, but I suspect that they will welcome you back with open arms.

Comment: Samantha, there's an organization / movement whose express purpose is to [welcome lapsed Catholics back into the fold](https://www.catholicscomehome.org/).

Answer (score 7):

Yes! You're Catholic.
Quick follow-up question though: did you receive a first Communion when you were younger?  If so, you probably just need to go to Confession before you can get in the Communion line again at Mass.  (That's true of any practicing Catholic who hasn't been in a while.)

If you *never* received Communion as a child, you may be required to attend an RCIA class ("rite of Christian initiation for adults") to re-learn the faith and get ready for a first Communion.  In most parishes, RCIA starts in the fall and runs through the next Easter, so don't dilly-dally and they will probably be happy to let you join this year's class late.

In either case, go talk to a priest before you take the advice of some guy on the Internet.

Comment: If you do the RCIA (as @Joe suggested) you would also be confirmed at the same time you receive your first communion.

Comment: Sam says she was confirmed as a youth, but if she isn't sure, part of the RCIA process is looking up the records of any sacraments you've already received.  So if she was never baptized or confirmed they'll find out and make sure it gets done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Roman Catholic. And was an altar boy for 18 years. Unless the doctrine has changed recently (which I highly doubt), so long as you never internally or externally denied the faith, then all you're due for is a good confession for all the Holy Days of Obligation that you missed of your own free will.

There are circumstances when your absence is not a sin. But that usually requires military deployment, personal illness, or medical emergencies.The only hard rule is you aren't supposed to take communion if you miss mass until you go to confession.

In general, a priest is who you should talk to. They'll guide you with open arms.

Answer (score 1):

Up until 2009, and according to the Canon Law, you stop being Catholic only **through a formal act** of defection, known in Latin as *actus formalis defectionis ab Ecclesia catholica*. From [this official document](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/intrptxt/documents/rc_pc_intrptxt_doc_20060313_actus-formalis_en.html):

> "1. For the abandonment of the Catholic Church to be validly configured as a true *actus formalis defectionis ab Ecclesia* so that the exceptions foreseen in the previously mentioned canons would apply, it is necessary that there concretely be:
>
> a) the internal decision to leave the Catholic Church;
> b) the realization and external manifestation of that decision; and
> c) the reception of that decision by the competent ecclesiastical authority."

This decree was however [eliminated in 2009](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/apost_letters/documents/hf_ben-xvi_apl_20091026_codex-iuris-canonici.html). (Thanks Matt Gutting for pointing this out)

Interestingly enough, even an excommunicated person [continues to belong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excommunication_(Catholic_Church)#Effects_of_excommunication) to the Catholic Church. It is the Church which imposes the excommunication on the person, and as such, it is not a personal, voluntary act of defection. Excommunication only restricts the person from receiving Sacraments and participating in celebrations (depending on the type of excommunication), but does not revoke their "right" to belong to the Church.

Also notice that the mark of Baptism is permanent, as the first document above reminds us:

> It remains clear, in any event, that the sacramental bond of belonging to the Body of Christ that is the Church, conferred by the baptismal character, is an ontological and permanent bond which is not lost  by reason of any act or fact of defection.

Comment: You might go even further: the penalty of excommunication could *only* meaningfully apply to someone who intended to remain Catholic.  To a non-Catholic it wouldn't seem a punishment at all.

Comment: The possibility of a "formal act of defection" was removed by the motu proprio [*Omnium in Mentem*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/apost_letters/documents/hf_ben-xvi_apl_20091026_codex-iuris-canonici.html) of Pope Benedict in 2009.

Comment: @MattGutting Oh wow! So now there is no such possibility? How does it happen then?

Comment: It doesn't. Once you're in, you're in. :-)